# jQuery plugin for uploading/preview multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know about a jQuery plugin that I can use for uploading mutiple images and previewing them before submitting? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the question by simply using the jQuery form plugin. 
I submit the form with this plugin (using ajax), upload the image, get it back and display it.

Answer (score 2):

There is this very nice one:
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/.